# local variable 'issue' referenced before assignment

Tags: python

My main function

```
    for record in event["Records"]:
        payload = json.loads(record["body"])
        if payload["action"] != "Create":
            continue
        issue_id = payload["documentId"]["id"]
        issue = client.get_issue(issue_id)

    data_id, main_id = parse_issue(client, issue)
```

Error: `local variable 'issue' referenced before assignment`
`data_id, main_id = parse_issue(client, issue)`

[Edited]
I need to be able to pass issue as I am also using it to one of my function above. Should I place the `issue = client.get_issue(issue_id)` outside for loop? How to fix?

```
def parse_issue(client, issue):

    data_id = issue.data["id"]
    main_id = issue.main_id

## More Code
    return data_id, main_id
```

Comment: Apparently the loop had 0 iterations or `continue` was executed in every iteration.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Putting the `issue` assignment outside of the loop will get rid of the error but it probably won't result in the code behaving as you expect since `issue` can change each iteration. Putting the assignment before the `if ... continue` will also get rid of the error, but may not result in the desired behavior. Give it a try and see what happens. Really, it would help to understand what you're trying to achieve with this code, including test input and expected output.

Answer (score 2):

It should be ok just to define your variable at the higher scope so that all the functions can see it. Everything in python is based on how much it's indented. So if you put down a variable at the same indent level as the for loop and the call to the function, it will store the value outside of the for loop and be accessible to both:

```
issue = 0
for record in event["Records"]:
    payload = json.loads(record["body"])
    if payload["action"] != "Create":
        continue
    issue_id = payload["documentId"]["id"]
    if issue_id is None:
        issue_id = payload["documentId"]["id"]
    issue = sim_client.get_issue(issue_id)

data_id, main_id = parse_issue(client, issue)
```

Comment: why `issue = 0`?

Comment: and this is not an issue of *scope* at all

Answer (score 0):

The reason is because `issue` never gets assigned a value. If there is nothing in `event["Records"]`, or `continue` always happens, then the `issue = client.get_issue(issue_id)` gets skipped.

Example:

```
def func():
    for i in range(0):
        x = 1 # never happens
    print(x)
func()
```

```
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'x' referenced before assignment
```

Disclaimer: Since I don't know the original purpose of the code, the fix described here just alerts you that `issue` does not exist, instead of giving you an error.

```
issue = None
for record in event["Records"]:
    payload = json.loads(record["body"])
    if payload["action"] != "Create":
        continue
    issue_id = payload["documentId"]["id"]
    issue = client.get_issue(issue_id)

if issue != None:
    data_id, main_id = parse_issue(client, issue)
else:
    print("Issue does not exist")

def parse_issue(client, issue):
    data_id = issue.data["id"]
    main_id = issue.main_id
    return data_id, main_id
```

Comment: so how do I fix it so i can get the value if the issue?

Comment: What is the code meant to do if there is no `issue`? If there is nothing in `event["Records"]`? Or if `payload["action"]` never equals `"Create"`?